# Unable to make the facebook "like" button to work on this site, any ideas?

Tags: wordpress, facebook

This is the site >> 
http://www.elsolitariomc.com

I'm using a plugin and also trying to use the usual facebook like button that it's explained here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Anyhow, the like button simply doesn't work or appears to have a # url.

I looked in StackExchange for any similar question, but all the problems seems to be different, any idea or link to an answer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Stackoverflow is the official facebook support channel, you may be better off asking there.

Comment: The problem is that I suspect that it's not a facebook problem but a configuration or web page setup, I'd been checking for that wrong behaviour on facebook related forums and I haven't found any solution so far.
I'll try there too, just in case.
Thank you

Comment: It works for me. I can see the addthis like button and then after "filed under music" there's another button.

Comment: it's displayed, but that's not the problem, the problem is that if you click any of those like buttons it won't work.
The first like it's the addthis plugin and the second like it's the official one from facebook.